# How do I write an SQL query to get the below output

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I need to write a query to get the Value in 'Name' column in the 'Manager_name' in output, if 'Manager' column from my table has an entry 'y' for any of the entries for the Dept.

Table:

| emp_id | Name | Dept | Manager |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | aa | n |
| 2 | b | aa | n |
| 3 | c | aa | y |
| 4 | d | aa | n |
| 5 | e | bb | n |
| 6 | f | bb | y |
| 7 | g | bb | n |

Output:

| emp_id | Name | Dept | Manager_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | aa | c |
| 2 | b | aa | c |
| 3 | c | aa | c |
| 4 | d | aa | c |
| 5 | e | bb | f |
| 6 | f | bb | f |
| 7 | g | bb | f |

Comment: Your question is unclear. Why `n` is "translated" into `c` and `y` into `f`?

Comment: Are you looking for a query that works in MySQL, or in PostgreSQL? What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Does something provides strictly one manager per department? Except client logic which is not safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the data we can easily believe the following to be true:

1. Each Emp_id is assigned to a unique individual
2. Each Employee works in a unique Dept
3. Each Dept has a unique Manager

For the required output we can retain the first 3 columns of the table and create a new column where we pull the manager name. For this, we need to have a table which has Dept and Manager name mapping.
We can easily get that by using following code:

```
Select Dept, Name as Manager_Name from table_name where Manager = 'y'
```

In the main table if we filter for Manager = 'y', the Name column will have the name of the manager. That's the only logic we need to apply.

Now all we need to do is to left join this new table on the existing table. Note that we don't need to create a new table, it could be simply nested in the query.
The detail code would look like this:

```
Select A.emp_id, A.Name, A.Dept, B.Manager_Name
from 
table_name A
left join
(
Select Dept, Name as Manager_Name 
from table_name where Manager = 'y'
) B
on A.Dept=B.Dept
;
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 3):

you can use a window function or a join to a subquery.

```sql
select emp_id, name, dept, manager_name
from table 
natural join (
   select dept, name manager_name 
   from table where manager = 'y'
) man_table
```

or

```sql
select 
  emp_id
, name
, dept
, first_value(name) over (partition by dept order by manager = 'y' desc) manager_name
from table
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT t1.*, t2.name manager_name
FROM table t1
JOIN table t2 USING (dept)
WHERE t2.manager = 'y'
```

PS. I do not see the guarantee that there exists strictly one manager row per department. If there is no such row or there exists more than one such row then the output will be incorrect.

PPS. If such row may absent use LEFT JOIN.